# Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length...Traceback (most recent call last), django mssql backend migration error

Tags: python, django, django-mssql-backend

Please, need help;
i use the last version of django 3.1, with django-mssql-backend to migrate ms sql database,
whene trying to migrate i faced this problem : auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length...Traceback (most recent call last);

```
   Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 245, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 572, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\schema.py", line 479, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_unique_sql(model, columns=[old_field.column]))
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\schema.py", line 861, in execute
    sql = str(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\Django\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\ddl_references.py", line 200, in __str__
    return self.template % self.parts
KeyError: 'deferrable'
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the fix. But I also ran into similar issue earlier. To fix this I rolled back to Django 3.0.x and then ran migrations.

Hope this will help you also :)

Comment: Yes, it works well with django 3.0, but i think the problème is within django 3.1 auth migration files, not mssql backend, may there is a solution to fix it without downgrade to django 3.0

Comment: The migration file hasn't changed between Django 3.0 and Django 3.1, and it works on different database backends, so it looks like the problem is that `django-mssql-backend` doesn't support Django 3.1. I think it could have to do with the new `UniqueConstraint.deferrable` attribute ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#models)).

Comment: It sounds like switching back to Django 3.1 after running the migration works. But you won't be able to run the migration in Django 3.1 until there is a new version of django-mssql-backend (or you patch it yourself). I don't see any issues about Django 3.1 support on GitHub, so you could create one, including the full traceback.

Comment: thank you for your replay, from my side, i tried to delete migration fils in "auth" app inside my virtualenv, then run py manage.py makemigrations, new migration file 001_initial was created, then running migrate cmd works well; thank you again;

Comment: No, you shouldn't delete migrations from your virtual env. If you ever upgrade Django, then the migration files and your `django_migrations` table will be out of sync.